# Encapsulating H.264 in MP4

Tags: mp4, h.264, video-codecs

I am going to write a program to encapsulate H.264 in MP4 container (wrapper). Is there any open specification about the bitstream?

RTP have a [specific payload format for H.264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184), does MP4 has a specific format for H.264?

Comment: [ISO/IEC 14496-14:2003 "Information technology -- Coding of audio-visual objects -- Part 14: MP4 file format"](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38538)

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, it is not open, it's commercial. Do I have to pay money just to download the file, or I must pay for using it too?

Comment: The specification is available for a fee. Having it's code and title you can find it online left there by peer developers. To my best knowledge there is no licensing fees for using/implementing it (unlike codec part of the MPEG-4 spec).

Comment: There should be libraries available you can use. Check gstreamer, ffmpeg, VLC et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The carriage of H.264|AVC in MP4 files is documented in two places:

- the ISO Base Media File Format (ISO/IEC 14496-12) which defines some core tools and is officially available for free on the [ITTF Web Site](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/). For some obscure reason, the same text is also available for purchase on the ISO web site.
- ISO/IEC 14496-15 which defines how to use the ISOBMFF for H.264|AVC streams. Unfortunately, that specification is not available for free, only corrigenda are. It can be purchased from [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=65216).

The MP4 file format (i.e. 14496-12) is NOT what you need here, as it defines the carriage of MPEG-4 Systems (e.g. MPEG-4 BIFS) in the ISOBMFF.

You should look at the numerous open source projects that support carriage of AVC such as: GPAC's [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac) or [MP4Box.js](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js), or [Bento4](http://www.bento4.com/), ...

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know the specification for H.264 over OGG?